# Trying to fill <select> dropdown with php resulting only in broken strings

Tags: php, html, forms, datetime

I'm trying to populate a select dropdown list with dates/times. I'm stuck though trying to echo a simple  tag into the html. For some reason, this code:

```
echo "<option>" . $fri->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "</option>";
```

results in a option reading " .  $fri->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "
Why is that?

Here's the rest of the code...nothing special.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

$fri = new DateTime('2014-08-29');
$fri->setTime(12, 00);
echo "<option>" . $fri->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "</option>";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely because your page is running from a place that does not execute the PHP.  So it's rendering just plain text.

Are you actually running this in a PHP page on a server that executes PHP?

Comment: oh! This php is inserted into an html document...do you think I should create a new php page for this or change the entire html document into a php document?

Comment: Well, it still needs to be executed as PHP.  Otherwise, you get nothing but text.  Change the extension on your page, and make sure your server is running PHP.

Answer (score 0):

i am using date() easy to handle and formating

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('2014-08-29'));
echo "<option value='".$date."'>" . $date . "</option>";
```